# strange issue when uploading file via asp.net, vs manually via FTP

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, web-config, authorization

I have a form in ASP.Net MVC, which allows you to upload a file.  The file is saved to a location on the server.  For example, if the domain is `www.test-domain.com`, and the local path is `c:\websites\test-domain.com\`, the image is stored in `/uploads/File/image.jpg`.

When I try to access this url `http://www.test-domain.com/uploads/File/image.jpg`, I get redirected to the `forms loginUrl="XXXX"` path in web.config.  To test, I removed the web.config entirely, and accessed the file.  This time round, I get a `401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials`.

I then uploaded another file via FTP this time, to `http://www.test-domain.com/uploads/File/image2.jpg`.  This one can be accessed without any problem.  I even tried download `image.jpg` as saved via Asp.Net, delete the file on server and re-upload the same exact file by FTP and it worked again!

It seems by FTP is working, while via Asp.Net somehow there are some access / authorisation requirement.  I do have authentication set in Asp.Net, but I removed the entire `web.config` file, and I still got an error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you compare the security details of both files? See if there are different users in `image2.jpg` than on `image.jpg`

Comment: @QuetiM.Porta Thanks for the heads-up.  The files did have different security permissions.  However, the issue was as explained in the answer, that I was moving the file and originally I didn't know this was happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out why this was happening, though it is totally unrelated to what I thought it was in the beginning.  I am uploading an image and resizing it.  I've looked further in the code, and for some reason I was creating an image in the temporary windows folder, and then moving it to the actual location using `File.Move`.

It seems that the security permissions created are different, than if I had to create the file directly in the final folder.  I've updated the code to create the image directly in the actual folder, and this is working fine.

Reference: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/08/24/717181.aspx